# RabbitMQ connection lost while consuming messages

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ with PHP. While consuming messages from RabbitMQ, we have magic in this piece of code:

```
while (count($callbacks)) {
                try {
                    $conn->wait();
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    //Log the message
                }
            }
```

This is working as infinite loop to receive messages as expected but what happening is if we lost connection to the RabbitMQ/RabbitMQ not up its going to catch block and returns nothing and printing bulk log messages. Is there any better way we can check for connection for RabbitMQ and stops the script? How can we achieve this? Any suggestions?

Comment: By adding break in this catch block we can terminate the rabbitmq consumption here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (count($callbacks)) {
                try {
                    $conn->wait();
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    //Log the message
                    break;
                }
            }
```